# Binning in pandas, TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: pandas, typeerror, binning

```
spending_bins = [0, 585, 630, 645, 680]
labels = ["<$585", "$585-630", "$630-645", "$645-680"]

school_spending_df["Spending Ranges (Per Student)"] = 

pd.cut(school_spending_df["Per Student Budget"],

spending_bins, labels=labels,include_lowest=True)
```

When I run this code I get this error message :

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

I tried switching labels to int.
tried to switch spending bins to str.

Comment: And `school_spending_df` is? Can you please share some sample data?

Comment: The error says it all, `school_spending_df["Per Student Budget"]` is of string type, or at least some of the cells are. Convert them into numeric, e.g. floats.